# Add a list and an iterator to form a new list

Tags: python, list, iterator, iterable

I tried:

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
b_list = [4,5]
...

call_function(a_list + iter(b_list))  # TypeError
```

Is there a better code than this:

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
b_list = [4,5]
...

new_list = a_list[:]
new_list += iter(b_list)  # no TypeError?
call_function(new_list)
```

Consider any iterator, I'm using `islice` in place of `iter`.

Comment: why not `new_list = a_list + b_list` ?

Comment: please see the last line

Comment: @BearBrown: the `b_list` is only used to construct an iterable/iterator... Afaik you should see it as a blackbox iterable/iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [python-3.5](/questions/tagged/python-3.5), you can use *iterable unpacking*:

```
call_function([*a_list, *iter(b_list)])
```

This works since:

```
>>> [*a_list, *iter(b_list)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Notice the asterisk (`*`) in front of both `a_list` and `iter(b_list)`. Furthermore `a_list` only has to be a *finite* iterable/iterator. So you can simply construct a list that concatenates finite iterables together.

Answer (score 3):

You can *generally* use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to join iterables:

```
from itertools import chain

new_list = list(chain(a_list, iter(b_list))) 
print(new_list)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers already address the workaround. Additionally, this line:

```
new_list += iter(b_list)
```

Does not throw an error, because it calls `list.__iadd__` which supports the addition of iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`__iadd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) which is the real function trigger by the syntactic sugar `+=` (That's why it doesn't create an error).

```
call_function(a_list.__iadd__(iter(b_list)))
```

Produce

```
>>> a_list.__iadd__(iter(b_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This is fun but not really good in term of readability to be honest. Prefer other answers :)

**EDIT**:

Of course to produce new_list, you have to make a copy of `list_a` has you did in your question.

```
a_list[:].__iadd__(iter(b_list))
```

Comment: I meant to form a new list (in question title). I didn't specify it in the question body, though

Comment: @Adam make sense. Edit answer but it is very close to the code in your original question.